# How to open my resource in that localhost:8080/test/index.html?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Tomcat started in eclipse and also I'm able to open the following URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/index.html
```

But, I'm not able to open my resource in that page.

Error that I am getting is:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /
type Status report
message http:/test/index.html
description The requested resource (/test/index) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

Comment: Do you have the index.html file inside the test folder in the tomcat ?

Comment: Actually, my project was made it an ear file and pasted in tomcat folder.

Comment: test is a project name..

Comment: Yes. Inside tomcat the project would have extracted to the test folder. So the index.html file should be inside the application. Verify it. If you post the code , It will be easy.

Comment: Tomcat does not directly support EAR files. It is a Servlet and JSP container, not a full Java EE Application Server.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the following steps in eclipse to deploy the project as a [WAR File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28file_format%29) and not as an [EAR File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29):

1. In the `Project Explorer` right click on `test` (which is the name of your project, if I got it right)
2. In the context menu choose `Export->WAR file`
3. In the dialog window that pops up click the `Browse...` button to choose the destination folder for the deployment. This should be the web application folder of your `Tomcat` installation: `<TOMCAT_INSTALLATION>/webapps` where `<TOMCAT_INSTALLATION>` is the folder you have installed Tomcat in.
4. Click `Finish`

Now start your Tomcat server. Assuming you have the `index.html` file in the `WebContent` folder of the `test` project in Eclipse, you should see the content of `index.html` in your browser when you open the URL.